# Capturing Column Names in Dynamic SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I'm in the process of updating some procs made for SQL 2008R2 to 2016 that are using a dynamic result set.

Assuming there is a procedure that always has exactly one result set, but the result set has a dynamic column return each time, is there a way to capture the column names at runtime in tsql without doing something janky?
I'm not worried about data types, just column names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no TSQL api to examine the resultset shape of a procedure that returns multiple different resultset shapes.  For normal procs you can use `sp_describe_first_result_set`.

If you can afford to actually run the procedure and examine the results, the least-janky solution is to use SQL CLR.  In CLR you get a SqlDataReader that you can use to examine the resultset shape.

Comment: Bummer. I had a feeling... I suppose I'll have to fire up Visual Studio...

Comment: Yep.  Stored procedures that return variable resultsets are always going to be a hassle.